# Textfield and floats in Swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, statements

I have 2 textfields. If they both has a float value bigger than 100, when you click on my button it should allow you to go to another page.

So far so good, however in my code the text field can't have either **int** or **float** or **doubles**...

What can I do?

Comment: change it to string. textField.text = "double value: \\(123.345)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lukas says you need to convert it to a string. If you are capturing the value in the textfield on button click, you need to convert it, like so:

```
if let doubleValue = Double(textField.text!) {

}
```

I think based on what you have said, you need to do something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var box1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var box2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Check: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Page1: UILabel!


    @IBAction func didPressCheckButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if let stringValue = box1.text {
            if let doubleValue = Double(stringValue) {
                if doubleValue > 100 {
                    print("Navigate to next page")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to modify the check so that you check if both text boxes have values over 100, but this is a starting point.

Comment: #totiG
`class ViewController: UIViewController {
    IBOutlet weak var box1: UITextField!
    IBOutlet weak var box2: UITextField!
    IBOutlet weak var Check: UIButton!
    IBOutlet weak var Page1: UILabel!
    if let doubleValue = Double(box1) {
        
    }`

Like this? (I just started yesterday, so this isn't that simple for me although I understand how simple it should be, if I just had a little experience..)

Comment: You are calling box1 which is a UITextField rather than the text property. You need to call if let doubleValue = Double(box1.text) { } - but this code needs to be inside a method, such as the action for your UIButton

Comment: I now wrote it inside my method, however I get an error saying: cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type '@ivalue String!'